# No activity found exception when send sms

Tags: android

I'm working on the android app in which i need to send the sms with image using intent but i'm getting exception `ActivityNotFoundException`. I'm trying in android 4.2

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shareviamms"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Java code:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);     sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms","com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
        sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/32X32.png"));
        sendIntent.setType("image/png");
        startActivity(sendIntent);
```

StackTrace

```
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shareviamms/com.example.shareviamms.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2187)
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:146)
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1239)
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5085)
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at com.example.shareviamms.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2151)
12-14 23:07:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: I added the manifest above.

Comment: Also post the full text of your error.

Comment: @hichris123 I posted the error logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With respect to the comments, I am updating the answer.
there are three ways to deal with the AcitivityNotFOund:

1)Keep trying that approach, but catch the ActivityNotFoundException.

2)If you get a ActivityNotFoundException, try to launch other apps that user may have installed (VZMessages, Zlango Messaging, Handcent, ChompSMS, etc).

3) If all of them fail, let your user know that you want to send a MMS, and then launch the intent without specifying the class. That way it is up to the users to choose an app that actually send MMS messages

Comment: Put the uri in the intent. Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND,uri.parse("file:///sdcard/32X32.png"))

Comment: And change it to ACTION_SENDTO

Comment: This is in android 4.4 but i'm trying on android 4.2

Comment: I checked personally I did not find this activity `com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity` in the Sony device 4.2 but it working well in Samsung Galaxy

Comment: both of the action items work.they have been added since API level 1. check this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND

Comment: Ok. If the answer helped you then please accept the answer and close the question. Thanks

Comment: I posted the stacktrace please see that

Comment: It clearly says that this caused the problem in your code:at com.example.shareviamms.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)

Comment: No issue it says about this com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity..it does not find the app which have this package

Comment: com.example.shareviamms.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20) check your main activity at line 20. It is clearly causing the crash.It says that in the logcat!!!

Comment: This is at line no 20 sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms","com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");

Comment: Is it possible that some devices does not have this message in built app which have this package `com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActi‌​vity`